# Mail function has stopped working on server

Tags: php, email, function, sendmail

my mail script is on online server. was working fine. but not now. I am confused why it has stopped sending mail. It shows the message that email sent, but no email is received in inbox. here is my php script:

```
$useremail = $_POST['myemail'];

    $friendemail = $_POST['friendemail'];

        $name = "support";

        $email = "support@example.com";

        $rec = $friendemail;

        $sub = "support Invitation";

        $body = 'the user '.$useremail.' has sent you message';

        $header="Content-type: text/html\n";

        $header .= "From: $name < ". $email ." >";

        $success_mail = mail($rec,$sub,$body,$header);
        if($success_mail){ echo "success0";} else { echo "Not sent";}
```

please help me !

Comment: What has changed on the server when it stopped working?

Comment: Did you check your spam folder? If your mail server receives mails in a pattern close to how spam arrives, it might classify it as spam

Comment: +1 So many headaches with test e-mails going to spam folders.

Comment: Some servers only allow a limited mail trafic and block your mail function if you are spamming mail, Check with your host if this is the case.

Comment: @tomhallam: No - the parameters passed to the mail program (assuming this is a *nix imlpementation and not MSWindows) are escaped anyway - double escaping can cause more problems.

Comment: I have tried these without escape, it prints the message 'success0' on screen but no email is sent, not even in junk or spam.

Comment: I was updating the files, But I did not make changes to this code. I dont know why it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

IME most issues relating to sending mail from PHP are problems with the MTA and nothing to do with PHP. If the system has stopped sending mail but your PHP has not changed then that's probably the case here too.

You've provided no information about what OS this is running on, nor how PHP is configured to use mail - this is very different on different operating systems.

> but no email is received in inbox

There's a whole lot of things which hapen in between sending an email and it arriving at it's destination. Typically it is queued for sending by the MTA at the sending end, passed to the MTA at the receiving end (optionally through intermediate MTAs), policy checks applied at the receiving end, passed on to the imap/pop service at the receiving end (possibly with further policy checks), retrieved by your mail client (again with further policy checks).

You need to look at each step of the process to find out where it is failing.

> mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['friendemail']);

WTF? this is just wrong.

> $header="Content-type: text/html\n";

You're not doing yourself any favours by trying to force non 7-bit ascii through SMTP. These days,  that shouldn't be a big problem, and is unlikely to be the cause of the error - but try sending plain text messages and see what happens.

oh...and looking at your code again I see that *you are sending plain text* so WTF is the html header for?

If you want any assurance of deliverability, then fix the encoding of your emails regardless if this is not the cause of the problem in this case.

Comment: it was sending email just a few minutes ago, the html body was sent, not plain text.

Comment: please help!  I am still looking for solution. :(